# Canada: "Governor General" vs "Governor in Council"

Tags: government, parliament, canada

Is "governor in council" the same as "governor general" in Canada?

If not, what does the "governor in council" do?

Comment: It's the Canadian variation on Queen-in-Council: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King-in-Council#The_Commonwealth It basically means an executive order made by the cabinet and formally approved by the Governor General.

Comment: Oh, so it's not a government position but an order?

Comment: It's not actually the order itself, but the nominal source of the order. Formally it's the Governor General as advised by the Privy Council, but in practice it's the cabinet making the order.

Comment: @RossRidge Please don't put answers in the comment section. Write a complete answer in the answer box. Use the comments for asking for clarifications, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the Canadian variation on [Queen-in-Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King-in-Council#The_Commonwealth)

An executive order is made by the executive, in the person of the Monarch (or their representative in Canada), on the advice of their ministers.  The nominal source of the order is said to be the "Governor in Council". Formally it's the Governor General as advised by the Privy Council, but in practice it's the cabinet making an order which is then formally approved by the Governor General.

(based on comments made by [ross ridge](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/11821/ross-ridge))